# List of arrays push in the list? with angular

Tags: arrays, list

```
 todolist:
  [
    { id:"1",
      text:"pen"},
    { id:"2",
     text:"notebook"},
    { id:"3",
      text:"highlighter"},
    ...
  ]
  
  todos:
  [
    { id:"1",
      title:"school"
      todolist:[
                 { id:"1",
                   text:"pen"},
                 { id:"2",
                   text:"notebook"},
                 { id:"3",
                   text:"highlighter"}
                ]
    },
    ...
  ]
```

I have a list of arrays todolist
and have a list todos with list todolist

I want to push the todolist-list to the todos as an object.
but how does it work?

Comment: You need to be more specific, which language you are using, how are you trying to push etc etc . Check these guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/tour  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to insert `todolist` elements into `todos` array, then use [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) method, as shown below:

```js
todos.concat(todolist)
```

Comment: it does not work.